# How to detect the reason of memory leaks according to the address providing by Leaks?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I have found a memory leaks through Leaks, but it only showed the address and the leaking bytes as below. I want to know how to detect the reason causing the memory leaks? Anybody know?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the extended detail panel (on the right).

[image]

Select one of the elements in the list and look at the extended detail panel, which shows the stack trace that caused the object to be created, as below:

[image]

Double click on it to see the code for that method.

For more about How to Use Instruments in Xcode, read the [raywenderlich excellent tutorial here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode)

Comment: Hi Ramshad, When I click a item in the Leaked Object, it doesn't give me any information in the Stack Trace. It shows "No stack trace is available for this leak". I wonder if I can find the object according to the address ‘0x9bf3890’ shown in the image above. Thanks~